# How can I get the windows security log in box for a website

Tags: html, windows, security, authentication

I'm New here, and I have a website with apache and I want to set it up so that a web page that needs to be logged in to, instead of having a forbidden page (which I am getting now) How can I get the windows security login box with a user name and password like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0cCj.png&gt; ?">

so, what is the HTML code for a password box like this, as I have searched for it, and the only thing that I can find is how to get rid of it, and not to get it on my website!

Comment: This doesn't come from HTML code, it comes from the authentication scheme of the server resource being requested.  You might have better luck at ServerFault instead of StackOverflow, asking how to use Windows Authentication in your Apache-hosted website.

Comment: @David: That's not Windows auth; it's HTTP basic auth.

Comment: That's not a Windows login box; it's an IE login box.  If you try it in Firefox or Chrome, you'll get a totally different box.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess